dbeaver 24.0.0 could not connect to hive via zookeeper through kerberos auth
I have my keytab file configured and dbeaver.ini configured with correct keytab and jaas.conf, the config worked fine for phoenix db access through the kerberos, so I can say the dbeaver setting with kerberos should be good.
The same setting worked fine when I use dbvisualizer, but dbvisualizer is not my favorite so I really want to use the dbeaver.
but when I try to connect hive via zookeeper, it failed with the error below.
Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Invalid status 21
my JDBC URL: jdbc:hive2://myhost:port;principal=hive/_HOST@myzone.net;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;ssl=true;SSLTrustStore=truststore.jks;SSLTrustStorePwd=mypwd*
the debug log showing the last content was Created InitSecContextToken:
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
then start from here it looks like all things restarted, log initiated from the beggining. repeat 3 times, then fail with **Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Invalid status 21
anyone knows what is happening and how should I fix this?
